# Strange things happen when using Object.defineProperty with let or var

Tags: javascript, var, let, defineproperty, hoist

1. Can anyone explain why `testVariable` has two different ouputs when using `let`. And why there isn't any runtime error when varibles with the same name are defined in `window` object?

```
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'testVariable', {
      value: 22
    })

    let testVariable = 12

    console.log(window.testVariable)   // result: 22
    console.log(testVariable)          // result: 12
```

2. But when using `var`, the outputs are the same.

```
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'testVariable', {
      value: 22
    })

    var testVariable = 12

    console.log(window.testVariable)   // result: 12
    console.log(testVariable)          // result: 12
```

3. Why following code runs correctly

```
  <script>
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
      value: 33
    })

    let a = 13
  </script>

  <script>
    console.log(a)    // result: 13
  </script>
```

4. But the following throws an error.

```
  <script>
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'a', {
      value: 33
    })
  </script>

  <script>
    let a = 13
    console.log(a)   // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'a' has already been declared
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is declared with `var` on the top level, as soon as the script tag *starts*, it's assigned as a writable property of the global object:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'testVariable'));
var testVariable = 12;
```

The same is not true for variables declared with `let` - they don't get put onto the global object:

```js
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'testVariable'));
let testVariable = 12;
```

When you use `Object.defineProperty` to define a property that's *already defined* on the object, and you pass a `value`, like with

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'testVariable', {
    value: 22
})
```

The prior value that existed on the object gets overwritten. So with your second code, you're defining a writable property named `testVariable` on the global object which then gets overwritten, and both `testVariable` and `window.testVariable` evaluate to `12`.

In contrast, with your first code, top-level variables declared with `let` create a global identifier, but do not get assigned to properties of the global object, so

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'testVariable', {
```

and

```
let testVariable =
```

are referring to different things.

---

> Why following code runs correctly, but the following throws an error

This one is quite interesting. According to the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-globaldeclarationinstantiation), when the environment prepares to execute a new `<script>` tag, it runs `GlobalDeclarationInstantiation` to set things up. It does, among other things:

```
1. Let envRec be env's EnvironmentRecord.
2. Assert: envRec is a global Environment Record.
3. Let lexNames be the LexicallyDeclaredNames of script.
4. Let varNames be the VarDeclaredNames of script.
5. For each name in lexNames, do
 - If envRec.HasVarDeclaration(name) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
 - If envRec.HasLexicalDeclaration(name) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
 - Let hasRestrictedGlobal be ? envRec.HasRestrictedGlobalProperty(name).
 - If hasRestrictedGlobal is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
6. For each name in varNames, do
 - If envRec.HasLexicalDeclaration(name) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.
```

Where `envRec` is the global Environment Record. (An Environment Record, or Lexical Environment, is a record of which variable names in a given scope refer to which values.)

With your code, the section of `GlobalDeclarationInstantiation` that is throwing is this section of 5:

> If envRec.HasLexicalDeclaration(name) is true, throw a SyntaxError exception.

In your third code, before the first script tag starts, when `GlobalDeclarationInstantiation` runs, the global environment record doesn't have a variable named `a`, so no error is thrown. In contrast, in your fourth code, when the **second** script tag starts, and `GlobalDeclarationInstantiation` runs, a variable named `a` declared with `let` already exists in the global environment record, so the `HasLexicalDeclaration` call returns `true`, and an error is thrown. (Variables declared with `let` create lexical declarations; variables declared with `var` create var declarations.)

Comment: Do you mean Object.defineProperty(window, 'testVariable', {
         value: 22
       }) is the same as var testVariable = 22 ?

Comment: Sometimes. With `Object.defineProperty`, if the property doesn't already exist, it'll default to `writable: false`. But when you create a variable on the top level with `var` in the *same script tag*. the property is put onto the window with `writable: true`. So if you use `Object.defineProperty` first, and then in another script tag use `var testVariable`, you'll be unable to change `testVariable` from its original value. (An error will be thrown in strict mode.)

Comment: Thank you very much @CertainPerformance, what you've told me is a lit complicated for me now, I will be doing more research based on your answers.